# PrimeNG DataTables with infinite scroll implemenation

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/scroll

PrimeNG provides Lazy loading which refresh data on scrollDown as well as on ScrollUp. I want to implement infinite scrolling which fetch data from server page by page on scrollDown and retain that data if I scrollUp.

There is no such documentation on PrimeNG website.
How can I achieve it with PrimeNG?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got an answer for this?

Comment: Didn't check on latest version. I moved to ngx- datatables.